# If $A_j$ is an increasing family of Hermitian operators such that $A_j\nearrow A$ weakly, for $A=\mathrm{LUB}A_j$, then $A_j\rightarrow A$ strongly.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am trying to prove the following proposition from Berberian's '[Notes on Spectral Theory](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/09/09-32.pdf)':

> Proposition 1: If ($A_j$) is an increasingly directed family of Hermitian operators, and if the family is bounded above in the sense that there exists a Hermitian operator $B$ such that $A_j\le B$ for all $j$, then $\mathrm{LUB}A_j$ exists. Writing $A=\mathrm{LUB}A_j$, we have $A_j\rightarrow A$ weakly, that is, $(A_jx|y)\rightarrow(Ax|y)$ for each pair of vectors $x,y$. In particular,
>   $$(A_jx|x)\nearrow(Ax|x)$$
>   for each vector $x$, and it follows from this that $A_j\rightarrow A$ strongly, that is,
>   $$\lVert A_jx-A_x\rVert\rightarrow 0$$
>   for each vector $x$.

In the above, LUB stands for 'Least Upper Bound', and $(a|b)$ denotes the inner product of vectors $a$ and $b$. The partial ordering $A\le B$ indicates that $B-A$ is a positive operator; since Berberian has not stated if $B$ is bounded or not, I am assuming it is unbounded. Is this correct, or is this theorem only valid if $B$ is a bounded operator?

I can follow Berberian's proof that $A$ exists, and $A_j\rightarrow A$ weakly. However for strong convergence he says:

> To prove that $A_j\rightarrow A$ strongly, we observe that $A_m\le A_j\le A$ for all $j$, and consequently $\lVert A_j\rVert$ is bounded. Thus the operators $B_j=A-A_j$ are positive, $\lVert B_j\rVert$ is bounded, and $(B_jx|x)\searrow 0$ for each vector $x$. The fact that $\lVert B_jx\rVert\rightarrow 0$ follows from the generalised Schwarz inequality
>   $$|(B_jx|y)|^2\le(B_jx|x)(B_jy|y)$$
>   in the usual way.

In this $m$ is some arbitrary index which we fix, and we assume without loss of generality that $j>m$.

I am having some trouble understanding this part. Firstly it is not clear to me how to show $\lVert A_j\rVert$, and hence $\lVert B_j\rVert$, are bounded without assuming $A$ is a bounded operator. Is this theorem not true for unbounded operators?

To show strong convergence, we need to demonstrate $(B_jx|B_jx)\rightarrow 0$. Substituting $y=B_jx$ into the generalised Schwartz inequality yields

$$|(B_jx|B_jx)|^2\le(B_jx|x)(B_jB_jx|B_jx).$$

The first term on the right approaches zero, but I am unsure how to deal with the second. I assume we need to show that this is bounded above, perhaps by $(A^3x,x)$. If we can take $\lVert B_j\rVert$ to be bounded then $(B_jx|B_jx)$ is bounded, but I am unsure how to deal with $(B_j^2x|B_jx)$ (though I feel intuitively that this should also be bounded).

Comment: Are these everywhere defined operators on a Hilbert space? Or is this just an inner product space?

Comment: This is in a Hilbert space.

Comment: If you have an everywhere defined symmetric operator $A$ on an inner product space $X$, then $A$ is closed because $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $Ax_n \rightarrow y$ implies the following for all $z$: $$(y|z)=\lim_n (Ax_n|z)=\lim_n(x_n|Az)=(x|Az)=(Ax|z),$$which implies $Ax=y$. If $X$ is complete, then $A$ must be bounded by the Closed Graph Theorem. So all of your symmetric operators must be bounded, because they are defined everywhere on a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are assuming the underlying space $H$ is a Hilbert space, and you're assuming the operators $A_j$, $B$ are defined everywhere on $H$. I'll assume $H$ is also complex. Then any symmetric operator on $H$ is bounded because it is closed, as noted in the comments.

I guess you were able to show that $a(x)=\lim_j (A_jx,x)$ exists for all $x$. Automatically $0 \le a(x) \le (Bx,x)$ holds for all $x\in H$ by the assumptions of your problem. And $B$ is bounded because it is symmetric on $H$. The function $a(x)$ is a quadratic form and the following limits exist:
\begin{align}
     A(x,y)&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n a(x+i^ny) \\
      &=\lim_j\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n (A_j(x+i^ny)|x+i^ny) \\
      &=\lim_j(A_jx|y),\;\;\;\; x,y\in H.
\end{align}
That's enough to imply that $A$ is a symmetric sesquilinear form. Because
$$ 0\le a(x)=A(x,x) \le (Bx|x),\;\;\; x\in H,$$
then
$$|A(x,y)| \le \|B\|\|x\|\|y\|,\;\;\; x,y\in H.$$
That gives a unique $0 \le A_{\infty} \le B$ such that $A(x,y)=(A_{\infty}x|y)$. In summary: $A_{\infty}$ is bounded and symmetric, and $0 \le A_{\infty} \le B$, with
$$\lim_j (A_jx|y)=(A_{\infty}x,y),\;\;\; x,y\in H.$$

Now you can apply the generalized Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $(x|y)_n=((A_{\infty}-A_n)x|y)$:
$$
   |((A_{\infty}-A_n)x,y)|^2=|(x|y)_n|^2\le (x|x)_n(y|y)_n.
$$
Setting $y=(A_{\infty}-A_n)x$ gives
\begin{align}
    \|(A_{\infty}-A_n)x\|^4&\le (x,x)_n((A_{\infty}-A_n)^2x,(A_{\infty}-A_n)x) \\
  &\le (x,x)_n (A_{\infty}(A_{\infty}-A_n)x,(A_{\infty}-A_n)x)\\
  &\le (x,x)_n \|A_{\infty}\|((A_{\infty}-A_n)x,(A_{\infty}-A_n)x) \\
  &\le (x,x)_n \|A_{\infty}\|\|(A_{\infty}-A_n)x\|^2
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
        \|(A_{\infty}-A_n)x\|^2 \le \|A_{\infty}\|(x,x)_n\rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } n\rightarrow\infty.
$$